# Setting up a Pi 3 without physical access to the router

Tags: boot

I just got a Pi and am interested in setting it up and getting started, but I don't have physical access to the router or an ethernet cable. Is there any way I can connect it to my Mac and get started that way?

Comment: Do you have wifi in which you know the SSID and authentication details? If so, connect your Pi to an HDMI monitor or TV, and through the GUI, configure the wireless connection. There's a little icon for your network devices up at the top left of the screen (if you're running Pixel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup the Wi-Fi completely headless. As stated on [The latest update to Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/another-update-raspbian/) you can provide a `wpa_supplicant.conf` on the /boot partition to setup the Wi-Fi. Don't forget to also create an empty `ssh` file to be able to actually access the pi as mentioned in [A security update for Raspbian PIXEL](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/a-security-update-for-raspbian-pixel/).

Then you should be able to find your Pi on the local network. You can try something like `nmap` to scan your local network.